# UPDATE INTENT DIALOG FLOW VIA API V1

Tags: api, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

My problem is that when I want to update an intent via API DIALOGFLOW V1 it returns Unknown Error, BUT I can list and create the intent via API V1, here is my code for the **update**:

```
url : https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/intents/f5eedaaa-f7d1-4e4e-b1fa-6aa66c94ca6f?v=20150910
method : PUT
DATA : {"id":"f5eedaaa-f7d1-4e4e-b1fa-6aa66c94ca6f","name":"FORDEBUG","auto":false,"contexts":[],"responses":[{"resetContexts":false,"affectedContexts":[],"parameters":[],"messages":[{"type":0,"condition":null,"speech":["KOKOKOOOKK","KOJKFKF"]}],"defaultResponsePlatforms":[],"speech":[]}],"priority":500000,"webhookUsed":false,"webhookForSlotFilling":false,"fallbackIntent":false,"events":[],"userSays":[{"id":"d891eb29-7233-4f47-901c-751cbde5fff4","data":[{"text":"KOKOK","userDefined":false}],"isTemplate":false,"count":0,"updated":0,"isAuto":false},{"id":null,"data":[{"text":"FJFLFOPF"}]}],"followUpIntents":[],"liveAgentHandoff":false,"endInteraction":false,"conditionalResponses":[],"condition":null,"conditionalFollowupEvents":[],"templates":[]}
```

and here is the return that I have :

```
{
    "id": "e5bf8ebf-f5e6-4568-8237-f69dcef6f5db",
    "timestamp": "2021-06-07T16:53:36.748Z",
    "lang": "en",
    "status": {
        "code": 400,
        "errorType": "bad_request",
        "errorDetails": "Unknown error errorid=0a4ffdc6-907a-4049-965d-509490bb428e"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format the question and shop shouting in the title

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Dialogflow V1 is already [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/release-notes#November_14_2019) last May 31, 2020 and no further operations can be performed. It is suggested to migrate to Dialogflow V2 so you can continue using the service.

> We are extending the V1 API shutdown deadline to May
> 31st, 2020. Migrate to the V2 API as described [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide).
>
> If you use **Dialogflow exclusively for Actions on Google**, you don't
> need to migrate your agent to the V2 API. However, note the following
> changes:
>
> - The Dialogflow simulator will show responses in the V2 format and the
>   "Copy curl" button will generate requests in the V2 format. This
>   should have no impact on the functionality of the Actions on Google
>   simulator.
> - You will no longer be able to call API methods for the V1
>   intents and entities resources. You will still be able to modify your
>   agent using the Dialogflow Console.

Once you have migrated to V2, you can update an [intent by batch](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents/batchUpdate) or [per intent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents/patch).

EDIT **20210609**

Here are the request body and call using curl. I'm not knowledgeable in php, but I suppose you can convert this to curl php.

But I assume that the content of the json will go to **data:**, the endpoint used in the curl command will be **url:** and **method:** will be either PATCH (for single intent) or POST (for batch intent update).

**Updating a single intent using request_patch.json**

```
{
   "name":"projects/your-project-id/agent/intents/your-intent-id",
   "displayName":"Image please",
   "trainingPhrases":[
      {
         "type":"EXAMPLE",
         "parts":[
            {
               "text":"Show an image"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"EXAMPLE",
         "parts":[
            {
               "text":"Show me an image"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "type":"EXAMPLE",
         "parts":[
            {
               "text":"Show me an image please"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Curl command:

```
curl -X PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
    https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/your-project-id/agent/intents/your-intent-id \
    -d @request_patch.json
```

Successful response:

```
{
  "name": "projects/your-project-id/agent/intents/your-intent-id",  "displayName": "Image please",
  "priority": 500000
}
```

**Updating batch intents using request_batch.json**

```
{
   "intentBatchInline":{
      "intents":[
         {
            "name":"projects/your-project-id/agent/intents/your-intent-id",
            "displayName":"Image please",
            "trainingPhrases":[
               {
                  "type":"EXAMPLE",
                  "parts":[
                     {
                        "text":"Show an image"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "type":"EXAMPLE",
                  "parts":[
                     {
                        "text":"Show me an image"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "type":"EXAMPLE",
                  "parts":[
                     {
                        "text":"Show me an image please"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Curl command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
    POST https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/your-project-id/agent/intents:batchUpdate \
    -d @request_batch.json
```

Successful response:

```
{
  "name": "projects/your-project-id/operations/operation-id-here",
  "done": true,
  "response": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.BatchUpdateIntentsResponse",
    "intents": [
      {
        "name": "projects/your-project-id/agent/intents/your-intent-id",
        "displayName": "Image please",
        "priority": 500000
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example for api v2 update intent on curl php

Comment: @AyoubHamoudi I edited my answer and included an example for both patch and batch update.

Comment: Please Ricco D can You give me an example update intent with patch to update training phrase and response, your example have only training phrases, thanks

Comment: And Also if you can how to add training phrase with variables and responses with call back function

Comment: @AyoubHamoudi I provided a link pointing on how to build the request on my answer. You can use my examples and just add responses and call back. But if you have further questions on adding training phrases, call back function, etc. I suggest to post a new question so the community can contribute.